# Group line plotting in D3 with d3.group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, grouping

I am working with a tidy-long data structure with three columns: date, ID, num_orders.

```
date          ID          num_orders
"2018-08-22"  1           3
"2018-08-23"  7           1
"2018-08-23"  10          1
"2018-08-23"  17          1
"2018-08-23"  19          1
.
.
.
```

I would like to plot a line for each ID with date and num_orders as the x- and y-axis respectively, using D3.js. I am using [this](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_several_group.html) as a model for what I am doing, but in that code, the author is using the `nest()` function, which is no longer used in v6 of D3; the method used now is `group()`. So my code now is:

```
const margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 };
const width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select('#my_dataviz')
    .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
        .attr('transform',
                `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
                
d3.json("./data.json")
    .then( function(data) {        
        const grouped_data = d3.group(data, d => d.ID);

        parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d')
        const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => parseDate(d.date)))
                        .range([0, width]);
        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
        
        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.num_orders)])
                        .range([height, 0]);
        svg.append('g')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

        const myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                            .domain(grouped_data.keys())
                            .range(d3.schemeSet3);
        
        svg.selectAll('.line')
            .data(grouped_data)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
                .attr('fill', 'none')
                .attr('stroke', d => myColor(d.keys))
                .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
                .attr('d', function(d){
                                return d3.line()
                                    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
                                    .y(d => yScale(d.num_orders))
                                    (d.values);
                });
    } )
```

So far I can get the axis with tick-marks to show up, but none of the lines are showing up, which makes me think the problem is in the final `svg.selectAll('.line')` statement. I'm pretty new to D3, so any guidance on this problem is appreciated. (And if you have any overall suggestions for my code, I also welcome this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

d3.line() is accepting arrays only, while d.values() is an iterator.
By converting it into an array the problem is solved.

Notice that, on the snippet I removed the parseDate because I am generating data as Dates.
You most likely will need to keep the parseDate

```js
const margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 };
const width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.timeDays(new Date(2020, 06, 01), new Date(2020, 10, 30));
var y = Array.from({length: x.length}, Math.random).map(n => Math.floor(n * 10) + 5);
var data = x.map((v, i) => {
  return {
    "date": v,
    "id": Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 + 1)),
    "num_orders": y[i]
  };
});

const svg = d3.select('#my_dataviz')
    .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
        .attr('transform',
                `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);


const grouped_data = d3.group(data, d => d.id);

parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
                .range([0, width]);
svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.num_orders)])
                .range([height, 0]);
svg.append('g')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

const myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                    .domain(grouped_data.keys())
                    .range(d3.schemeSet3);

const line = d3.line()
              .x(d => { return xScale(d.date); })
              .y(d => yScale(d.num_orders));

svg.selectAll('.line')
    .data(grouped_data)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', d => myColor(d[0]))
        .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
        .attr('d', (d) => line(Array.from(d.values())[1]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. One quick question though, the colors are not behaving as expected; they are showing up greyed out. I tried using a similar approach (i.e., `.attr('stroke', d => myColor(Array.from(d.keys)))`), but it doesn't appear to be working...

Comment: Check the updated snippet: `.attr('stroke', d => myColor(d[0]))`

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was having to resort to a "forEach" loop over the `grouped_data` object. This is a much better solution!

Comment: All day looking for this answer, till now! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse the data on the line generator

```
const margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 };
const width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select('#my_dataviz')
    .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
        .attr('transform',
                `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
                
d3.json("./data.json")
    .then( function(data) {        
        const grouped_data = d3.group(data, d => d.ID);

        parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d')
        const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => parseDate(d.date)))
                        .range([0, width]);
        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
        
        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.num_orders)])
                        .range([height, 0]);
        svg.append('g')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

        const myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                            .domain(grouped_data.keys())
                            .range(d3.schemeSet3);
        
        svg.selectAll('.line')
            .data(grouped_data)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
                .attr('fill', 'none')
                .attr('stroke', d => myColor(d.keys))
                .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
                .attr('d', function(d){
                                return d3.line()
                                    .x(d => xScale(parseData(d.date)))
                                    .y(d => yScale(d.num_orders))
                                    (d.values);
                });
    } )
```

Comment: Your suggestion is definitely a good one, and I've incorporated it into my code. But it doesn't appear to be solving the problem.