# How do I adjust if/else nomenclature for d3 v7 (d3.nest to d3.groups)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble adjusting if/else terminology to adjust for changes from d3.nest (v5) to d3.groups (v6 onward).

I've adjusted from

```
.data(function(d) { return d.values; })
```

to

```
.data(([, values ]) => values)
```

without any issues.  However, the code I'm working off for a source has an if/else statement that is causing me some trouble.  I need to adjust the following and I'm at a loss (selectLegis is a filtered dataset):

```
.data(selectLegis, function(d){
          return d ? d.key : this.key;
        })
```

What are `d` and `this.key` in the new nomenclature and how do I rewrite the code here?

Edit: added sample data below

```
year, state, wvalue, lvalue,
1980, AL, 0.4, Example1,
1980, AL, 0.3, Example2,
1984, AL, 0.2, Example1,
1984, AL, 0.7, Example2
```

Edit: reproducible example below

```
var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 }
  var h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom
  var w = 700 - margin.left - margin.right
  var formatDecimal = d3.format('.2')

d3.csv('15/data.csv').then(function (data) {

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.year = +d.year;
      d.state = d.state;
      d.wvalue = +d.wvalue;
      d.lvalue = d.lvalue
  });

// Scales
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0,w])
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([h,0])

  y.domain([
    d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) { return d.wvalue })]),
    d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return d.wvalue })])
    ]);
  x.domain([1968, 2016])
  
// Define the line
var valueLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.wvalue); })

// Create the svg canvas in the "d3block" div
var svg = d3.select("#d3block")
        .append("svg")
        .style("width", w + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
        .style("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
        .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "svg");

//nest variable
var nest = d3.groups(data, 
  d => d.state, d => d.lvalue)

  // X-axis
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(formatDecimal)
    .ticks(7)
  // Y-axis
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .tickFormat(formatDecimal)
    .ticks(5)
    // Create a dropdown
    var legisMenu = d3.select("#legisDropdown")

    legisMenu
    .append("select")
    .selectAll("option")
        .data(nest)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", ([key, ]) => key)
        .text(([key, ]) => key)

  // Function to create the initial graph
  var initialGraph = function(legis){

    // Filter the data to include only state of interest
    var selectLegis = nest.filter(([key, ]) => key == legis)

      var selectLegisGroups = svg.selectAll(".legisGroups")
        .data(selectLegis, function(d){
          return d ? d.key : this.key;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "legisGroups")

    var initialPath = selectLegisGroups.selectAll(".line")
      .data(([, values]) => values)
      .enter()
      .append("path")

    initialPath
      .attr("d", d => valueLine(d))
      .attr("class", "line")

  }

  // Create initial graph
  initialGraph("Alabama")


  // Update the data
  var updateGraph = function(legis){

    // Filter the data to include only state of interest
    var selectLegis = nest.filter(([key, ]) => key == legis)

    // Select all of the grouped elements and update the data
      var selectLegisGroups = svg.selectAll(".legisGroups")
        .data(selectLegis)

        // Select all the lines and transition to new positions
            selectLegisGroups.selectAll("path.line")
               .data(([, values]) => values)
                .transition()
                  .duration(1000)
                  .attr("d", valueLine(([, values ]) => values))
  }

  // Run update function when dropdown selection changes
  legisMenu.on('change', function(){

    // Find which state was selected from the dropdown
    var selectedLegis = d3.select(this)
            .select("select")
            .property("value")

        // Run update function with the selected state
        updateGraph(selectedLegis)

    });
      
  // X-axis
  svg.append('g')
      .attr('class','axis')
      .attr('id','xAxis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h + ')')
      .call(xAxis)
    .append('text') // X-axis Label
      .attr('id','xAxisLabel')
      .attr('fill','black')
      .attr('y',-10)
      .attr('x',w)
      .attr('dy','.71em')
      .style('text-anchor','end')
      .text('')
  // Y-axis
  svg.append('g')
      .attr('class','axis')
      .attr('id','yAxis')
      .call(yAxis)
    .append('text') // y-axis Label
      .attr('id', 'yAxisLabel')
      .attr('fill', 'black')
      .attr('transform','rotate(-90)')
      .attr('x',0)
      .attr('y',5)
      .attr('dy','.71em')
      .style('text-anchor','end')
      .text('wvalue')
})
```

Comment: Can you add sample data?

Comment: This is a bit like comparing apples to oranges... the first two snippets are about binding data to a grouped selection (see the second paragraph in https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data). The function is executed per group and the returned result is the data to be bound, i.e. determining **what** data is bound. The third snippet, on the other hand, is using a *key function* (see the 5th paragraph in the docs linked to above) which determines **how** data is bound to nodes. You can safely delete the first half of your question and focus entirely on the use of the key function...

Comment: ...which is causing your problems. To be able to help you out, though, you'll need to provide some more code to give some context about what you are actually trying to do. Try to set up a [mcve], ideally, put it into a runnable Stack Snippet.

Comment: Edited to provide reproducible code.  I'm working on putting it into fiddle but am slipping a little on the learning curve as I haven't produced one from scratch before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

altocumulus was correct that the issue was how the data were being manipulated/called.  I did more digging and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66054877/group-line-plotting-in-d3-with-d3-group).

I had to replace the initial path attribute `.attr("d", valueLine(([, values]) => values))` with `.attr('d', (d) => valueLine(Array.from(d.values())[1]))`.  I also had to replace the code further down within the `updateGraph` function under `selectLegisGroups .attr` for it to update properly.